# Am I interpreting predicted Poisson regression correctly?

Tags: r, interpretation, poisson-distribution, model, epidemiology

I have a dataset with time to outcome (t3) and the outcome (mmop_num) plotted by Poisson regression using the predict() function in R. (1) Am I correctly interpreting the y-axis as the likelihood of having the outcome at a given t3?

```
t3irr_model <- glm(mmop_num ~ t3, data = acl, family = "poisson")
t3 <- data.frame(t3 = acl$t3)
pred <- predict(t3irr_model, newdata = t3, type="response", se = T)
```

(2) Is there a good book for reading about how to calculate relative risks like as described here: [How do I interpret the figure output from package dlnm in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62597/how-do-i-interpret-the-figure-output-from-package-dlnm-in-r) ? I would like to plot risk ratio vs. t3 on a continuous scale using splines, GAMs, etc. Is there a good place to read about that? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: The response in a Poisson regression is the fitted value of the Poisson parameter.  It's very difficult to interpret this as a likelihood.  In particular, it cannot be any kind of probability due to the possibility that it exceeds $1.$ Here's a reproducible example: `n <- 100;
x <- 1:n;
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = rpois(n, 3 * x / n));
df$y.hat <- predict(glm(y ~ x, data = df, family = "poisson"), type="response");
with(df, {plot(x,y); lines(x, y.hat)})`

Comment: Could it be interpreted as an estimate of the likelihood in this instance with outcome recorded as 0/1? I watched this ~7:00 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyU2CkHrfQk, and I thought the poisson regression would be analogous in interpreting probability of result. The interpretation as an estimated likelihood makes sense with the data but let me know your thoughts

Comment: Also, it may be important for me to also note that I am only modeling data within my original x range without projecting out further

Comment: When responses are binary, a Poisson model is usually implausible.  You need to describe your data.  Regardless whether you plan to extrapolate, the mere mathematical possibility that a Poisson response can exceed $1$ demonstrates it is not a probability.

Comment: I ran poisgof() and got a p-value of 0.99 when testing the goodness of fit for the Poisson assumption. What is the best way to model probability of a binary outcome with a continuous x-axis? This article suggests that Poisson regression with robust standard errors is okay for a binary outcome https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-018-0519-5